# Regular expression in python replace

Tags: python, json, regex, jq

Is there any way using regular expression in python to replace all the occurrences of `,` (comma) after the flower braces `{`

Data is of the following format in a file - `abc.json`

```
{
"Key1":"value1",
"Key2":"value2"
},

{
"Key1":"value3",
"Key2":"value4"
},

{
"Key1":"value5",
"Key2":"value6"
}
```

This should result in following -

```
{
"Key1":"value1",
"Key2":"value2"
}

{
"Key1":"value3",
"Key2":"value4"
}

{
"Key1":"value5",
"Key2":"value6"
}
```

As you can see the `,`(comma) has been removed after every braces `}`.

Would be helpful if this can be achieved via jq as well, apart from python REGEX

Comment: you can use lookbehind if you are using python `(?<=}),`

Answer (score 1):

Test Source: https://regex101.com/r/wT6uU2/1

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'},')
test_str = u"{\n\"Key1\":\"value1\",\n\"Key2\":\"value2\"\n},\n\n{\n\"Key1\":\"value3\",\n\"Key2\":\"value4\"\n},\n\n{\n\"Key1\":\"value5\",\n\"Key2\":\"value6\"\n}"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

But use replace instead

> replace }, -> }

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
import re

s="""{
"Key1":"value1",
"Key2":"value2"
},

{
"Key1":"value3",
"Key2":"value4"
},

{
"Key1":"value5",
"Key2":"value6"
}"""

pattern=re.compile(r'(?P<data>{.*?}),', re.S)

print pattern.findall(s)

s1=pattern.sub(r'\g<data>', s)
print s1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to process the resulting JSON in jq, it's probably easier to wrap it in brackets `[{...}, {...}]` to make it a JSON array. Then, you can use `.[]` in jq to unwrap the array.

Answer (score 0):

Before you even consider other options, you really should go back to the source that generated that file and make sure it actually outputs *valid* json.

That said, you could use JQ to manipulate the contents as a raw string to add brackets, then parse it as an array to them spit out the contents.

```
$ jq -Rs '"[\(.)]" | fromjson[]' abc.json
```